# What is the Scala and Java version for AWS Glue ETL job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

So far I'm using scala 2.11 with Java 8 to build the library used by the Glue ETL job. We're planning to upgrade to Scala 2.12 with Java 11 but not sure if they are supported by the Glue ETL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glue versions are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/release-notes.html). The latest version supports `Spark 2.4.3`.

In [Spark 2.4.3](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-3.html), the default version of Scala is 2.11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also confirmed with AWS that Glue ETL only supports Java 8 for the moment. The is are feature requests for supporting Spark 3.x with Java 11 but it's not yet implemented.

Comment: @seiya No problem. Glad my answer was helpful:-)